# Why (void) between two comma separated statements in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, void

The following code comes from an implementation example of `std::lexicographical_compare` on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare):

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
bool lexicographical_compare(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                             InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2)
{
    for ( ; (first1 != last1) && (first2 != last2); ++first1, (void) ++first2 ) {
        if (*first1 < *first2) return true;
        if (*first2 < *first1) return false;
    }
    return (first1 == last1) && (first2 != last2);
}
```

Why is there a `(void)` in the loop, and what would be the consequence of not putting it there?

Comment: Someone is planning to add `(void)` before `++first1` because `++first1, (void) ++first2` could still instantiate some `operator,` declared somewhere, which might still cause trouble.

Comment: @cpplearner Someone, huh?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the type of the value returned by prefix increment operator of `InputIt1` type has overloaded comma operator then expression `++first1, ++first2` may invoke it, so casting result of `++first2` to `void` ensures that no overloaded comma operator is invoked since overloaded comma operator can not accept `void` as parameter.

Comment: Insane language specifications confirmed. Has anyone actually seen *legitimate* usage of overloading that?

Comment: @Passer By ::boost::assign

Comment: Huh? How is it used? Just checked out boost::assign

Comment: @PasserBy `using namespace boost::assign; vector<int> v;  /* ... */ v += 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;` That appends the values to the end of `v`.

Comment: @Passer By https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Expected.h#L556

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a paranoid implementer covering their bases because they don't know the exact details of the types that they are dealing with.

You may or may not know that `operator ,` can be overloaded for types. Because of this, there may be unintentional consequences when using a statement such as `++first1, ++first2` or even just `first1, first2`.

The `(void)` cast is put there so that any overloaded `operator ,` cannot take effect, as operators cannot operate on the incomplete `void` type.